# Fancybox can't scroll to overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a Fancybox dialog that loads AJAX content. The user can click a "+" to add a row inside. As the rows add up, the dialog becomes higher than the screen size. A scrollbar appears, **but the dialog can't be scrolled down**, it keeps going back up.

How do I fix this?

Comment: any chance you can share a link or create a demo that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, my bad. For future reference, here's the fix.

**Never** try to dynamically update and reposition your Fancybox.

## What I tried

```
$('#stuff').fancybox({
    ... stuff
    onUpdate: function() {
        $.fancybox.update();
        $.fancybox.reposition();
    }
});
```

*Ultimately, on every update, the Fancybox should center itself and reposition itself.*

**However!** In reality it attempts to do this every few milliseconds. That causes Chrome's inspector to freeze whenever the Fancybox is active and also causes the scrolling to fail (it keeps trying to update the size/position while you're trying to scroll it causing  a fail).

## The correct way

Update every time you expect your size to change manually.

- When changing the dialog content (if it's an AJAX)
- When showing inside-errors or adding new divs inside
- etc